# Time ordering and the `garch` function in `tseries` package in R

Tags: r, time-series, residuals, garch

I have fitted a `garch` function using the `tseries` package in R, and I have observed that the series of residuals produced by the GARCH model begin with 'NAs', equal to the max order of the model.

E.g. For a GARCH(3,5) with 2000 observations, I am observing that the first 5 values for the residuals are NA, and then the remaining 1995 are non-NA values.

My question is, why are the NAs at the start of the residual series? I have set my data up so that the most recent data is at the start of the vector, and the oldest data is at the end of the vector. I would have thought that the last 5 residuals (observations 1996 to 2000) are the ones that are NA, as that is when the process "begins".

Is there some sort of assumption in R that the inputs in time-series modelling are arranged in a traditional chronological order, such that the first observation should be the oldest one? Is there any way to tell the `garch` function that the data is arranged in reverse chronological order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some sort of assumption in R that the inputs in time-series modelling are arranged in a traditional chronological order, such that the first observation should be the oldest one?

I think there is. Some classes such as `ts` have time series attributes making time indexing explicit, but if you use a simple vector, time series function in R will usually assume its first observation is the oldest one.

> Is there any way to tell the `garch` function that the data is arranged in reverse chronological order?

I do not think you should attempt making the `garch` function deal with a reverse-ordered time series; rather, reverse it yourself before inputing into the function. For a vector `x`, you can use `rev` to reverse the order: `rev(x)`.